# Перестал работать Eclipse ADT: This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit new version

Tags: windows, android-sdk, eclipse

В Perfertence -> Android всплывает ошибка:

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508. Please update ADT to the latest version.
```

Но ведь

[image]

Это можно как-то лечить?

**UPD:** `Check for Updates` не помогает, после проверки всплывает `No updates were found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, мне всё надоело, и я решил проблему кардинально.

Я снес `eclipse` к чертям собачьим и скачал `Android Studio`, меня он сразу впечатлил, так как он сделан на основе `IntelliJ IDEA` от `JetBrains`.

Так что вопрос можно считать решенным :) и ответ пометить как верный.